# Model Validation in Rails to test if a number can be nil or some positive integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

how to validate a model with one integer property say customer_id in order table which allows customer_id but if its available it should be great then 0

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 3, maximum: 10}
  validates :customer_id,  numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 1}, presence: false
end
```

i did it using above but it is not accepting null values in number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add `allow_nil: true`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-nil

Answer (score 1):

## Validation for a number that can be nil or some positive integer

You just need to add `allow_nil: true` to your validation clause. This will skip the validation if the field is `nil`.

So it should look like:

```
validates :customer_id, numericality: { grater_than_or_equal_to: 1}, allow_nil: true
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-nil